# Width in % in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, width

I have problem with Google Chrome (not Firefox, IE, Opera or Safari).

When i set width as percentage Chrome from time to time make the divs 1 or 2 pexels to wide.

Any ideas or is this a known issue in Chrome?

Html:

```
<div class="table w60">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell w20">
            <div class="head_grey">Code</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell w55">
            <div class="head_grey">Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell w25">
            <div class="head_grey end">Vat</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.table
{
    background:#FFFFFF;
}

.table .row
{
    clear:left;
}

.table .row .cell
{
    float:left;
}

.head_grey
{
    padding:3px 5px 3px 5px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background:url(/images/head_grey.png);
    font-weight:bold;
    border-color:#A3A3A3;
    border-width:1px 0px 1px 1px;
    border-style:solid;
    height:14px;    
}

.table .row .cell .end
{
    border-right-width:1px;
}

.w5 { width:5%; }
.w10 { width:10%; }
.w15 { width:15%; }
.w20 { width:20%; }
.w25 { width:25%; }
.w30 { width:30%; }
.w35 { width:35%; }
.w40 { width:40%; }
.w45 { width:45%; }
.w50 { width:50%; }
.w55 { width:55%; }
.w60 { width:60%; }
.w65 { width:65%; }
.w70 { width:70%; }
```

Comment: Can you include a code snippet of a place where this happens?

Comment: This looks as if it's actually going to be tabular data.  Why not use a table instead?

Comment: This is just an example where i have the problem that i can fit in without adding 1000+ rows of css thats why i made this table layout, i was fast and short. Have same problem in many places not only table-like layouts. The class .table, .row .cell and .end was added just for this example.

Comment: I have come across inconsistent browser rendering when width units are in percentage, most especially with Chrome, when the value includes decimal places.